# Does Scipy linkage ward depends on node order?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am using scipy linkage ward to perform hierarchical clustering.
When testing for reproducibility, I discovered that if I reorder by data I get different results. So far my explorations are as follows:

1. Take original data (dataframe)
2. Create a copy with reordered rows
3. Compute pairwise distance matrix
4. Verify distance matrix is the same, except reordered
5. Obtain two trees with `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` with `np.triu_indices_from(dist, k=1)` passed as condensed distance matrix
6. Verify both trees monotonic
7. Observe discrepancy in the resulting trees
8. More importantly: observe discrepancy with cluster labels obtained with `cut_tree`

Is this the expected behaviour? If not, what am I doing wrong? Sorry, I cannot share my data, but it does have a few 0-distance pairs.

Comment: If you remove the 0-distance pairs, do you still get different results from different orderings of the data?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, I do